# Three.js webpack advantages

Tags: webpack, three.js

I'm trying to set up a three.js project with webpack and everything seems to work. But compiling and working with all those modules seems very sophisticated to me. I'm a web developer and always worked with script tags inside an .html and a simple python server. Also, the compiling on my mac needs 1min to compile, so it is also time consuming.

What are your advantages using webpack/browsify?

Comment: This may be a bit too broad of a question.

Comment: If your Webpack is taking 1 minute to compile in dev mode, it's doing you a disservice. What's your configuration like, are you watching 1000s of files, or using hundreds of modules? If used properly, it should compile in *seconds* at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack is an incredibly powerful build tool / bundler. At it's core it does just that, bundles your javascript together so you don't have to use script tags in an html file. In fact you don't have to touch any html files at all and have them automatically generated.

Since it's infinitely configurable and has a rich ecosystem you can do many things with it. The most common one is to write some future version of javascript not yet understandable by browsers and transpile it to older javascript.

If you look at examples of how GLSL is imported via html, it's very cumbersome. With webpack you can write your GLSL in `my_shader.glsl` files and import them efficiently and concisely.

With a proper setup, you should be able to see your changes either in realtime, or automatically refreshed, almost instantly in development mode.

The compilation (building/bundling) you should do only ever so often when you want to deploy, for development usually it takes a while to spin up the dev environment, but then it should be very beneficial.

There are many many advantages of using build tools, too many to list here. The disadvantage is that they all have some learning curve and webpack's is pretty steep.